# XML processing instructions not appearing in the prolog

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I have  a C# program that generates XML from another application. I am taking attribute values of these XML tags and attempting to display them in a formatted table using XSLT. I have been able to get the stylesheet(xsl) reference to appear in the xml document, but it appears at the bottom therefore displaying just the original xml. How can I get this processing instruction tag to appear right after the declaration?
This snippet puts the processing instruction at the very bottom of the xml doc.

```
XmlProcessingInstruction newPI;
        string PItext = "type='text/xsl' href='stylesheet.xsl'";
        newPI = b.CreateProcessingInstruction("xml-stylesheet", PItext);
        b.AppendChild(newPI);
```

If any additional info is needed please let me know and I appreciate any input.

Thanks

Comment: What does Prolog have to do with this?

Comment: @Magus He's probably referring to nodes that appear before an XML root element, which includes what is called the [prolog](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#sec-prolog-dtd). I edited the title to place it in lowercase.

Comment: @Magus - You're thinking the wrong kind of prolog. http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-prolog-dtd

Comment: @helderdarocha & Daniel Haley you are both correct, apologies for the confusion Magus

Comment: Yeah, it was just the capital that threw me off.

Comment: @user3744860 Do you append anything to the XmlDocument before appending `newPI`?

Comment: I create a txt doc and then load the XmlDocument into it. Then I attempt to append the XmlProcessingInstruction. No initial appending is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `b.InsertBefore(newPI, b.DocumentElement)`.